# Python turtle invalid command (From Think Python book)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to follow along with the exercises in the "Think Python" book and ran into a problem trying to get turtle to work. [Here is the exercise I'm on. (4.1)](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/html/thinkpython2005.html)

The code they want me to execute looks like this:

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
print(bob)
turtle.mainloop()

bob.fd(100)
bob.lt(90)
bob.fd(100)
```

But when I execute it, the turtle doesn't move and I get the following error when I close the window:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Phil\PycharmProjects\untitled\mypolygon.py", line 6, in <module>
        bob.fd(100)
    File "C:\Python\3.5\lib\turtle.py", line 1637, in forward
        self._go(distance)
    File "C:\Python\3.5\lib\turtle.py", line 1605, in _go
        self._goto(ende)
    File "C:\Python\3.5\lib\turtle.py", line 3158, in _goto
        screen._pointlist(self.currentLineItem),
    File "C:\Python\3.5\lib\turtle.py", line 755, in _pointlist
        cl = self.cv.coords(item)
    File "<string>", line 1, in coords
    File "C:\Python\3.5\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2308, in coords
        self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".1395635997272"
```

I'm not sure what the debugger is saying, and I can't really continue until I figure out where I went wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bob.fd(100)` line (and all following lines) will never be reached as the `turtle.mainloop()` call starts a loop (as its name implies).

Change your code so that it reads:

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
print(bob)

bob.fd(100)
bob.lt(90)
bob.fd(100)
```

And everything should work.

(Since you are not handling any events in your program, I would recommend not calling `turtle.mainloop()` for now; if you do want to follow the book's example, make sure to do as it says: "*To draw a right angle, add these lines to the program (after creating bob and **before calling mainloop**)*").

There are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059592/tkinter-tclerror-invalid-command-name-4302957584), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588583/get-tkinter-tclerror-when-closing-python-turtle-before-it-finished-its-draw) and [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue6639).